# What would happen if I pulled a yo-yo on ice?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

If I pulled the string of a yo-yo that was on ice so there was no friction, would it just rotate in place, or would it slide along the ice? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that there is absolutely no friction. Then in this case the free body diagram looks like this:

[image: fbd]

### Force

As you can see that there is a net force $F$ acting on the yo-yo (including the thread) so there would definitely be some non zero acceleration due to Newton's second law, which implies there would be translation/sliding of yo-yo.

### Torque

Now if you write the torque expression from the center of mass, then there is only one force generating the torque which is the tension of the thread, which is, in turn, generated due to $F$. Thus any non zero force $F$ would result in a non zero tension, which in turn would generate a non zero torque because there is no other torque which can cancel the thread's torque. Since there's a net torque, there must be a non zero angular acceleration which implies the yo-yo will also undergo rotational motion.

### Conclusion

The yo-yo will undergo both translation and rotation. According to the free body diagram in the image, the yo-yo will rotate in the clockwise direction and move towards the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Forget ice, we'll call it a frictionless plane. 
To have rotation, you must have a force that is applied off center (a torque).

If the applied force (pull on the string) is tangential to the yo-yo (completely off centre), it will only roll in place.

If you apply a force exactly at the center (like when the yo-yo is completely unwound) it will only have a linear motion and slide along.

If you apply the force somewhere in the middle, it will both roll and slide.